# How to on hover of element style itself and another element

Tags: html, css, hover

So I have a `div` with a `paragraph` and `bold` inside, like:

```css
.tt {
  border: 2px solid;
  text-align: center;
  padding:  0 0 3% 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="tt">
  <p>This text stays quiet</p>
  <b>But this underlines</b>
 </div>
```

So what I wanted was to on `hover` of that `div` style it, let's say `cursor: pointer` and the **bold** text underlined. Is there any way of making the same code for both, like in the same `div:hover` style both elements?

**-- EDIT --**

```css
#tt {
  text-align: center;
  border: 2px solid; 
  padding: 3% 0 3% 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="tt">
  Now this underlines<br>
  <b>but this stays quiet</b>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add styling to all children of the hovered element. Like this:

```css
.tt {
  border: 2px solid;
  text-align: center;
  padding:  0 0 3% 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.tt:hover b {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<div class="tt">
  <p>This text stays quiet</p>
  <b>But this underlines</b>
 </div>
```

Comment: So lets say instead of paragraph I have plain text inside div and I want to underline that text and not the bold text, I'm going to edit question with that question

Comment: You can't do this with plain text. If the plain text in the element would be underlined on hover, the `<b>` tag would also be underlined. If you would want only 'Now this underlined' to be underlined, wrap it in a tag.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can easily achieve that like this. Live demo below.

Just keep in mind that changing the cursor on `:hover` doesn't really serve a purpose, since you could just set the `cursor: pointer` to always be on that element and you'd have the same effect.

```css
.tt {
  border: 2px solid;
  text-align: center;
  padding:  0 0 3% 0;
}

.tt:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.tt:hover b {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<div class="tt">
  <p>This text stays quiet</p>
  <b>But this underlines</b>
 </div>
```